# How to exit a Windows Forms Application in C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a Windows Forms Application in C# that uses only one form. When I want to exit and close the application, I add the code

```
private void Defeat()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Goodbye");
    this.Close();
}
```

to the class `Form1 : Form`, which is the form class that was automatically created by Visual Studio. But when this code runs, I get the following message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

A picture of the message:

[image: Error message]

What is the problem?

How should I exit my application?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You first need to quote your string so the message box knows what to do, and then you should exit your application by telling the application context to exit.

```
private void Defeat()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Goodbye");
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you want to close the application, please try this:

```
    DialogResult dialog = new DialogResult();

    dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close?", "Alert!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: This is the only one which is working for me on windows server 2019.

Answer (score -2):

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Close();  //”this” refers to the form
}
```

Comment: If you do this in a WinForms app, you'll end up with the exception 'System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.' in your program.cs->Main() method.